# Pandas: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1/' while extracting month from date strings with single digit months

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

```
all_data['Month'] = all_data['Order Date'].str[0:2]

all_data['Month'] = all_data['Month'].astype('int32')

all_data.head()
```

I believe I'm receiving this error due to the fact that the single digit months(January-September) have one less value than months October-December within the 'Order Date' Column.

Example:

its written as 4/12/2017

instead of 04/12/2017

Not really sure how to approach this to solve the issue, any suggestions would gladly be appreciated it, thanks!

Comment: Instead of string slicing, why not `str.spilt('/')` or that kind of thing? Or parse directly to `datetime` using `strptime`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to split the date string by [`str.split()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and then get the first  split substring by `.str[0]`, as follows:

```
all_data['Month'] = all_data['Order Date'].str.split('/').str[0].astype('int32')
```

Alternatively, you can also convert the date string to datetime format by [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then get the month by [`dt.month`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.month.html), as follows;

```
all_data['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(all_data['Order Date']).dt.month
```

It would be helpful to specify also the format string, if your date string format is in `mm/dd/yyyy`:

```
all_data['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(all_data['Order Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y').dt.month
```

Adding the format string with `format='%m/%d/%Y'` avoids ambiguity whether it is month first or day first and also possibly speed up the process of date parsing by Pandas.

**Result:**

```
print(all_data)


   Order Date  Month
0   4/12/2017      4
1  04/12/2017      4
```

Answer (score 0):

For better accuracy you could use:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "name": ["Tom", "Andy", "Lucas"],
        "DoB": ["08/05/1997", "04/28/1996", "12/16/1995"],
    }
)
df["Month"] = pd.to_datetime(df["DoB"]).dt.month

print(df)
```

Output:

```
    name         DoB  Month
0    Tom  08/05/1997      8
1   Andy  04/28/1996      4
2  Lucas  12/16/1995     12
```

Reference: https://towardsdatascience.com/working-with-datetime-in-pandas-dataframe-663f7af6c587